# JMenuBar items disappearing behind panel

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I have a simple JMenuBar with 4 items and a Panel with some textFields spinners and comboboxes.

now if I use the Spinner or some other Components in the Panel the Jmenu items seem to open behind the panel , I cant see it but I can still use it. Im working with the netBeans GUI tool. Do i have to set the JMenuBar allways on top or something ?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
the Jmenu items seem to open behind the panel
```

you have issue with [Mixing AWT with Swing JComponents](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/mixing/) and better would be to change

```
java.awt.Panel myPanel = new Panel
```

to the

```
java.swing.JPanel myPanel = new JPanel
```

Comment: +1  Don't mix Swing with **any** AWT components unless you have very good reason to do so.

Answer (score 0):

JMenu should land on top by default.  You should place your content in some panels rather than placing it directly into the JFrame.  For instance, you could use a border layout and place most of the layout in a JPanel that is in the CENTER, and then have some addition buttons on the SOUTH JPanel.  The constants here are BorderLayout constants.   Without your code it is hard know see what you did wrong.